# Do the same words have different lemmas for different POS?

Tags: stanford-nlp

If there are two words that have different POS but are spelled the same, then are there different lemmas for such words?

For instance, words 'care' as a noun and 'care' as a verb have the same or different lemma?

Is there NEVER such a situation where "different" words have the same lemma?

Answer (score 0):

There are rare instances where a single word can have a different lemma depending on part of speech; an example is **saw**. For saw/NN, the lemma is saw, for saw/VBD, the lemma is see.

I'm not sure what you meant by the last question. All the time different words have the same lemma: look, looks, looking, and looked all have the lemma **look**.